# Manwiches made on the stove

Tags: food-safety

I am making manwiches for Halloween, how long can I keep it warm on the stove so that the kids can eat off and on during the day?

Comment: Do you have a crock pot you can put the filling in? That would be the easiest solution so you don't have to watch and stir so much.

Comment: See also the tag wiki on food safety, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. Scroll down to "The most asked question: I left this out... is it still safe?".

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate -- it's how long the food can be held warm on a stove.  ( stoves heat stuff, so it is *not* room temperature).

Comment: @Joe I wondered about that, the question doesn't really explain whether it's above or within the danger zone. Anyway, we also have questions concerned with keeping food permanently above it. I also linked the tag wiki, and made sure that it specifically addresses this case. But we can also link the questions of constant hot-keeping, or reopen and close with one of them as a target.

Comment: @rumtscho : Do we have a question of how long things can be kept heated on a buffet line?  That'd be closer.

Comment: @rumtscho I'm with Joe here - our standard target explicitly states "room temperature". Yes, there is the danger zone explained, but somehow it doesn't feel right here. OP asks about keeping it warm on the stove. We should at least change the target. Couldn't find a good one of the cuff, that's why I posted a (temporary) answer. Halloween *is* today, after all...

Comment: @Joe we have http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37243/. I am also sure that we have another question which addresses perpetual soup in the question already, not just as an answer, but I couldn't find it just now.

Comment: @rumtscho: Is this the perpetual soup question you're referring to: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20978/never-ending-soup-is-it-actually-safe That question suggests cooling it down and reheating it, so I think it's a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The *Danger Zone* for food is between 5 C / 40 F and 60 C / 140 F.

Assuming that you cook your food first, you will exceed the recommended 75 C / 165 F initial heat, so keeping it hot *above the danger zone* even for hours is safe.

Whether it is a good idea to do so depends a lot on your dish...